# Página em paisagem, e não a figura

Tags: latex

Estou criando um arquivo no latex, e precisa que uma das páginas fique em paisagem, pois tem várias figuras. Entretanto, apenas as figuras estão ficando em paisagem, e não a página em si.

Estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{\label{fig:sub_2018_OSPO-OSISAF_media}OSISAF E OSTIA}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=4cm]{Figuras_resultado/fig_sub_mes_estacao/sub_201801_OSPO-OSISAF_media.jpg}
 ... várias figuras
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

Como está ficando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como quero que fique:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Obrigada pela atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### pdflscape

Se você está utilizando um editor LaTeX PDF, utilize o [pdflscape](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdflscape), que adiciona suporte PDF ao pacote `lscape`. Conforme o código de exemplo a seguir:

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}
...
\begin{landscape}
...
\end{landscape}
```

Um exemplo pode ser visto no [Overleaf](https://pt.overleaf.com/read/bjybxxftjjdd).

#### lscape

Ou o pacote [lscape](https://ctan.org/pkg/lscape)

```
\usepackage{lscape}
...
\begin{landscape}
...
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Olá. Deu certo! Obrigada!